# Fetch data from LocalHost and display data with React Js

Tags: reactjs, spring, api, text, localhost

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfs0Q.png)I am new to React, it would be great if I get some help.I created an Api getUserDetails and tested it on Postman which showed perfect results, but now I am trying to get data from this local Api in my ReactJs application, but unable to fetch any data .What should I do to fetch the data from localHost Api in my ReactJs Application.Here is my react code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state ={
      user:[],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/getUserDetails?name=Anisha")
    .then(response=>response.text)
    .then(data=>{
      this.setState({user:data})
    })
  }

  getUser(){
    const users=this.state.user.map((u)=>
    <div className="userBox">
      <div>{u.name}</div>
    </div>
    )
    return users;
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>{this.getUser()}</div>
    )
  }

  
}
```

and the backend code is as follows:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    
    @GetMapping("/getUserDetails")
    public String getUserDetails(@RequestParam String name) {
        return "Requesting Details of User" +  name ;
    }
```

Comment: Soo, what is your problem exactly ? Where is the question ?

Comment: I am not able to fetch data in my reactJs Application, so what should I fix In my react code to fetch data from localhost

Comment: Could you please check if you are getting an error because of CORS policy from browser's console

Comment: Thanks, @AbhishekAnand , It was an error because of CORS policy. I added an google chrome extension for it, which solved my error.